# Is it possible to have single public repo in AzureDevops Project which is privet?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project in AzureDevOps with multiple repositories. Currently, this project and all its repositories are private, behind authentication.

I would like to have one repository in this project be public (without authentication) and can't find the solution.

So, I am wondering is this even possible and how?

Thx

Comment: I dont think this is possible to be mixed in a project. You'll need to create a separate Project that is public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new public project inside your Organization and those repositories will be publicly available. I believe you cannot have a public repository inside a private project.

So the options that I am aware of are:

```
Organization -> Public  Devops project -> Public Repositories
Organization -> Private Devops projects -> Private Repositories
```

Useful Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/make-project-public?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts